# Spring boot ssl how to trust all valid certificates

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

I have enabled ssl in my spring boot application and anytime I want to use a Rest service like googleapis or facebook I have to add the certificate in the truststore.

I use openssl to get the certificate:

> openssl s_client -connect googleapis.com:443

and I import it into the truststore :

> keytool.exe -import -noprompt -trustcacerts  -alias googleapis.com
>   -file googleapis.com.cer -keystore     app-server.p12 -storepass *****

The problem is that it's very inconvenient to manage, when the certificate expires I have to update the certificates in the truststore everytime.

Also even if I add the right certificate sometimes I get an error:

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I know these certificates are valid so, is there a possibility to trust them automatically without adding them in the truststore?

Here is my ssl configuration

```
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:keystore/app-server.p12
    key-store-password: ******
    key-alias: app-server
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    trust-store: classpath:keystore/app-server.p12
    trust-store-password: *****
    trust-store-type: PKCS12
    keyStorePath: config/keystore/app-server.p12
```

Also I had to add system properties in the main method

```
private static String keyStorePath;

private static String keyStorePassword;


@Value("${server.ssl.keyStorePath}")
public void setKeyStorePath(String keyStorePath) {
    ClientUiApplication.keyStorePath = keyStorePath;
}

@Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
public void setKeyStorePassword(String keyStorePassword) {
    ClientUiApplication.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(ClientUiApplication.class, args);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keyStorePath);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
}
```

Another important detail, I need a truststore because I use self-signed certificates generated with Keytool. Without, my services cannot communicate with each other.

Comment: why there is a dislike ? what's wrong with my question ?

Comment: @wargre ok it's just the usual ssl configuration so I didnt think it was necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You give the code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ClientUiApplication.class, args);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keyStorePath);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
}
```

This means that you force the java trust store to be the trust store you provide. The default trust store is not in use anymore.

So yes, you have to add every needed root certificates in this trust store to not have the issue you describe.

Why do you need to have a specific trust store?

- If there is no use, remove that.
- If you have a specific additional certificate you have to trust, you'd better add this certificate to the default trust store (the `jre/lib/security/cacerts` file)

Comment: thanks, I use that configuration in the main method because I needed it for Eureka but I 'm not sure I still need it because I don't use Eureka anymore (Kubernetes only now). But I stlil need a trustore to allow communication between my services with Feign under ssl  because my services use self signed certificates. In a production environment with valid certificates probably I don't need trustores, I don't use restricted communictatin between services. I don't know the difference between the default java trustore and the one I configured.

Comment: let's go for some answer. First of all, default java truststore (cacerts) contains a lot of root certificate ( for instance global sign, let's encrypt, digicert... ) So that java can access a lot of https website without any issue. The truststore you use is a truststore you created from nothing. As an example, if you trust the let's encrypt root certificate, you will be able to access a lot of services (stackoverflow included). If you trust only the current stackoverflow certificate, you will be able to access stackoverflow until the stackoverflow certificate is rotated

Comment: Note that you say you use kubernetes. for what you describe, you want to use https for inner services. It is perfectly legit if you want to secure your cluster. Today, especially with kubernetes, you can use service mesh with mtls policy enforced. It means your application speak and listen http but the data is encrypted with TLS on the wire.  It means it is simpler on application side, but a little bit more complex on operational side ( some tools to check from a wide list: istio, linkerd, maech, ...)

Comment: Ok thank you for this information, I was not aware being a beginner with the ssl mechanisms. I will find out about mtls it seems to be an interesting tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can also  Bypass SSL Certificate Checking using CloseableHttpClient

```
public static CloseableHttpClient getCloseableHttpClient()
{
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
    try {
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom().
                setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE).
                setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy()
                {
                    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }).build()).build();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        LOGGER.error("KeyManagementException in creating http client instance", e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        LOGGER.error("NoSuchAlgorithmException in creating http client instance", e);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        LOGGER.error("KeyStoreException in creating http client instance", e);
    }
    return httpClient;
}
```

It will trust automatically all the certificates and saves you from **SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException**

Note this method is not recommended in Production